# Reloading TableView when a UIViewController is being dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

The problem here is that I'm presenting `EditCommentVC` modally, over the current context of the `CommentVC` because I want to set the background of the `UIView` to semi-transparent. Now, on the `EditCommentVC` I have a `UITextView` that allows the user to edit their comment, along with 2 buttons - `cancel` (dismisses the `EditCommentVC`) and `update`  that updates the new comment and push it to the database.

In term of code, everything is working, except that once the new comment is being pushed and `EditCommentVC` is being dismissed, the `UITableView` on `CommentsVC` with all the comments is not being reloaded to show the updated comments. Tried calling it from `viewWillAppear()` but it doesn't work.

How can I reload the data in the `UITableView` in this case?

```
@IBAction func updateTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let id = commentId else { return }
    Api.Comment.updateComment(forCommentId: id, updatedComment: editTextView.text!, onSuccess: {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let commentVC = CommentVC()
            commentVC.tableView.reloadData()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }, onError: { error in
        SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error)
    })

}
```

The code in the `CommentVC` where it transitions (and passes the `id` of the comment). `CommentVC` conforms to a `CommentActionProtocol` that passes the `id` of that comment:

```
extension CommentVC: CommentActionProtocol {

    func presentActionSheet(for commentId: String) {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default) { _ in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CommentVCToEditComment", sender: commentId)
        }
        actionSheet.addAction(editAction)
        present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "CommentVCToEditComment" {
            let editCommentVC = segue.destination as! EditCommentVC
            let commentId = sender as! String
            editCommentVC.commentId = commentId
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the callback of `Api.Comment.updateComment` invoked in a background thread? If so, you could wrap your call to `reloadData` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block.

Comment: It is an `async` call, yes. Regarding the `DispatchQueue.main.async`, should I do that in the `viewWillAppear()` ? Because I tried that, still no effect.

Comment: No, `viewWillAppear` is automatically called on the main thread, no need to dispatch there. I meant to dispatch the code you have inside the callback block of `updateComment`, including the commented-out call to `reloadData` that's crashing. You also should call `dismiss` from the main thread.

Comment: I've updated the code in the OP, still crashing though. The error states `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @Dani you need to show your main view controller code, especially the place where you present this view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see atleast **2 problems** here:

1. You are creating a **new** `CommentVC` which you should not do if you want to update the `tableView` in the **existing** view controller.
2. Since you have mentioned that `Api.Comment.updateComment` is a an **asynchronous** call, you need to write the UI code to run on the **main thread**.

So first you need to have the instance of the `commentVC` in a variable inside this viewController. You can store the instance of the view controller from where you are presenting this view controller.

```
class EditCommentVC {

    var commentVCdelegate: CommentVC!   
    // Rest of your code

}
```

Now you need to pass the reference commentVC in this variable when you are presenting the edit view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "CommentVCToEditComment" {
        let editCommentVC = segue.destination as! EditCommentVC
        let commentId = sender as! String
        editCommentVC.commentId = commentId
        editCommentVC.commentVCdelegate = self
    }
}
```

Now you need to use this reference to reload your tableView.

```
Api.Comment.updateComment(forCommentId: id, updatedComment: editTextView.text!, onSuccess: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        commentVCdelegate.tableView.reloadData() // - this commentVC must be an instance that you store of the your commentVC that you created the first time
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}, onError: { error in
    SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error)
})
```

Comment: Okay, I tried this. Moved the `let commentVC = CommentVC()` outside and yet, crashes with the same error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @Dani where have i asked you to move it outside? I said you need a reference from it from where it was created first. Ok maybe i was not clear enough. I will edit the answer once you show the code for the other viewcontroller and this viewcontroller in full.

Comment: I guess I chose my words poorly. It's within the scope of the `EditCommentVC`

Comment: @Dani can you add the code where you present the view controller to the question?

Comment: Yes, I did :) I just updated it to show you where exactly that code is being called. It's in a `UIAlertController`

Comment: Tried this. Twice. Still not reloading the `tableView` data though. It updates the comment on the database but after `EditCommentVC` is being dismissed, the `tableView` on `CommentVC` is still not reloading the data.

Comment: @Dani i forgot to update the name of the delgate in the async call. I have edited the answer. If that doesn't work. You might need to show your code. You can share it in chat maybe?

Comment: No, I figured out that you forgot to do that. I did it myself. That's not a problem really. What I'm thinking about is that I might need to make another `API` request to update `comments` array? I'm kinda lost already. But sure, chat would be fine, yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178471/discussion-between-rakesha-shastri-and-dani).

Answer (score 0):

Well, i had this problem too, and the solution i found was to use **Protocol**. I would recommend you to **search how to send data back to previous ViewController**. That way, when you **dismiss the `EditCommentVC`**, you then send back a value(in my case i send true) to the **previous** ViewController(in your case, CommentVC), and then you'll have a function in CommentVC checking if the value is true and if it is, reload the TableView.

Here, let me show you an example of how i used (those are the names of my ViewControllers, functions and protocols, you can use whatever you want and send whatever data you want back):

In your **CommentVC**, you'll have something like this:

```
protocol esconderBlurProtocol {
    func isEsconder(value: Bool)
}

class PalestranteVC: UIViewController,esconderBlurProtocol {

func isEsconder(value: Bool) {
        if(value){
        //here is where you can call your api again if you want and reload the data
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Also, dont forget that you have to set the delegate of EditCommentVC, so do it when you're presenting EditCommentVC, like this:

```
let viewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetalhePalestranteVC")) as! DetalhePalestranteVC
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        viewController.delegate = self
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
//replace **DetalhePalestranteVC** with your **EditCommentVC**
```

And in your **EditCommentVC** you'll have something like this:

```
class DetalhePalestranteVC: UIViewController {

var delegate: esconderBlurProtocol?

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        delegate?.isEsconder(value: true)
    }

}
```

That way, everything you dismiss **EditCommentVC**, you'll send back True and reload the tableView.

Comment: "_you then send back a value(in my case i send true) to the previous ViewController(in your case, CommentVC), and then you'll have a function in CommentVC in ViewWillAppear checking if the value is true and if it is, reload the TableView_" It already sounds like a bad approach.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri can you explain why its sounds like a bad approach?

Comment: The tableView is supposed to be reloaded when a particular condition is met. So the right place to do this is where the condition is met. viewWillAppear is for things that need to be done when the view is about to appear. Reloading a tableView when some condition is met on another view controller is not one of those things. You use delegation for that. Unless you need to make changes in multiple places in which case you use notifications. I am not saying your answer will not solve the problem, it might most probably, but it is not a good way to do it.

Comment: Its not called on viewWillAppear, it was my mistake to type that. Its called when the previous ViewController calls the protocol and sends back data to that Controller.

Comment: You are doing the same thing as me. Passing an reference of the parent view, but the difference is you are hiding it behind a protocol.